# too many indices for array while splitting array

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I am trying to read a csv file and store the data into a 2d array. However, before I put the data into the 2d array I want to take the header data which is at the top of the csv and store it in its own array.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open ('parkinsons.data.csv','r') as csv_file:
    row_count = sum(1 for row in csv_file)  # fileObject is your csv.reader





readArray = np.zeros(shape=(row_count,24));
print(readArray)

with open ('parkinsons.data.csv','r') as csv_file:
    lineCount = 0;
    for line in csv_file:
        if(lineCount == 0):
            temp = np.char.split(line, sep=',')
            lineCount = lineCount + 1;
            print(temp) ##When I print this out I can see the entire array
            print(temp[0])## When I try to print this out i get an error




csv_file.close()
```

Here is the error I get when I try to print out a specific position from the array (example temp[0]

[image]

However, if i just print temp then it displays all the data. If I try to use np.shape, it says the array is empty.

I am sort of new to python and numpy so any help is welcomed, I saw a few people with the same sort of issues but I understood why they got them I cant understand why I am getting it. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `np.char.split` instead of the basic python string split?  `list.split(',')`?

Answer (score 0):

To first answer your question, the data structure you store `temp` in is an array, whose only member is a list. If you were to do,

```
np.size(temp)
```

The output would be `()`. If you really want to, you can access the contents of `temp` by doing:

```
print(temp[()])
```

but this is (highly) not recommended. Here is a better way:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('temp.csv') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    
    for row in csv_reader:
        if (csv_reader.line_num == 1):
            header = row
```

where the example csv file I used (`temp.csv`) is,

```
head, shoulders, knees, toes
1, 2, 3, 4
4, 3, 2, 1
```

Here, `header` should be the array of the header data you requested.

PS: I may be a little bit bribed since I love this package, but this is much easier to accomplish with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')
header = csv_file.columns
```

which would give you the same result.